# How to execute Scala script from Gradle?

Tags: scala, gradle

I have a Scala script that looks something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=${SCALA_HOME}:${PATH}

exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#

Console.println("Hello, world!")
```

Is there some way in Gradle to set the version of Scala to be used, have it implicitly set `SCALA_HOME`, and execute the script?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in feature for this. The way to tackle this is to declare two tasks: A `Copy task` that downloads the Scala distribution and unpacks it to a local directory, and an `Exec` task that sets the `SCALA_HOME` environment variable to the copy task's output directory and executes your script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of executing Scala from Gradle. It is a nascent attempt to build a plugin using Scalafmt.  Of note is how nasty it is to use static values.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.geirsson:scalafmt-core_2.11:0.4.2'
    }
}

task scalafmt << {
    String target = "object FormatMe { List(Split(Space, 0).withPolicy(SingleLineBlock(close)), Split(Newline, 1).withPolicy{ case Decision(t@FormatToken(_, `close`, _), s) => Decision(t, List(Split(Newline, 0)))}.withIndent(2, close, Right)) }"
    def config = org.scalafmt.config.ScalafmtConfig$.MODULE$.default
    def range = scala.collection.immutable.Set$EmptySet$.MODULE$
    println org.scalafmt.Scalafmt.format(target, config, range).formattedCode()
}
```

I know this is not quite on topic but I couldn't find anywhere else to put this and I hope it is of some value to people who ended up here for the same reason I did.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has an Exec task in which you can set the environment to be passed to the new process.  You could pass SCALA_HOME through that.